# javascript enable disable in every row table withphp array

Tags: javascript, php

i have a table from array in php so i put select option that have javascript to control disable/enable, .my problem is , javascript only working at 1st row of table..and the other rows are not working..can somebody help me with this thank you in advance...my code as :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Status1').change(function() {
    if (($(this).val() === 'T') || ($(this).val() === 'M')) {
      $(‘#uia’).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $(‘#uia’).attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="Status1" name="Status1[]">
    <option value="T" >PILIHAN 1</option></option>
    <option value="M" >PILIHAN 2</option></option>
    <option value="S" >PILIHAN 3</option></option>
</select>

<select id="uia" name="uia[]">
    <option value="E" >PILIHAN 1</option></option>
    <option value="D" >PILIHAN 2</option></option>
    <option value="K" >PILIHAN 3</option></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: you have 2 closing tags for option everywhere and you have invalid single quotes in the `$('#uia')` selectors.

Comment: there's no array here (in fact, no PHP at all) and no HTML table, so I'm not sure why you mentioned that. On a basic level have you checked your code for errors? There are basic HTML markup errors and some Javascript errors, plus you're using the wrong method (attr instead of prop) to set enabled/disabled (as per the jquery docs for those methods!). I have converted your sample into a runnable snippet. You'll notice it doesn't actually run due to the basic syntax errors. Fix those first and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have some errors in your syntax.

- you have 2 closing tags for the option elements (`<option value="T" >PILIHAN 1</option></option>`).
- you have invalid single quotes in your jQuery selectors (use `'` instead of `’`).

As @ADyson has noticed, use `.prop( propertyName, value )` instead of `.attr( attributeName, value )` for disabling and enabling elements.

```js
$('#Status1').change(function(){
  if(($(this).val() === 'T') || ($(this).val() === 'M')){
   $('#uia').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  }else{
   $('#uia').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="Status1" name="Status1[]" >
<option value="T" >PILIHAN 1</option>
<option value="M" >PILIHAN 2</option>
<option value="S" >PILIHAN 3</option>
</select>

<select id="uia" name="uia[]" >
<option value="E" >PILIHAN 1</option>
<option value="D" >PILIHAN 2</option>
<option value="K" >PILIHAN 3</option>
</select>
```

Note that this doesn't disable the `#uia` element on load.
To achieve this you could set the `#uia` element to disabled by default or add an onload event to the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <tbody> 
        <?php do  {?>
                        <?php $Sellcount++ ; ?>
                        <tr>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#Status1').change(function(){
                                    if(($(this).val() === 'T') || ($(this).val() === 'M')){
                                        $('#uia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                    }else{
                                        $('#uia').attr('disabled', false);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }); 
                        </script>
                        <td clas ="TD-Ubah2"><?php echo $Sellcount; ?></td>
                        <td class ="TD-Ubah2" nowrap><?php echo $row_rsSell['Nama']; ?></td>
                        <td class ="TD-Ubah2"><?php echo $row_rsSell['IC'];?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" id="IC" name="IC" value="<?php echo $row_rsSell['IC'];?>">
                        <td class ="TD-Ubah2"><input id="notel" name="notel" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_rsSell['NoTel_HF']; ?>"></td>
                        <td class ="TD-Ubah2">
                             <select id="Status1" name="Status1" >
                                <option value="" >SILA PILIH</option>
                                <option value="A" <?php if($row_rsSell['Status'] == 'A'){ echo "selected"; }?>>PILIHAN 1</option>
                                <option value="L" <?php if($row_rsSell['Status'] == 'L'){ echo "selected"; }?>>PILIHAN 2</option>
                                <option value="M" <?php if($row_rsSell['Status'] == 'M'){ echo "selected"; }?>>PILIHAN 3</option>
                                </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class ="TD-Ubah2">
                                <select id="uia" name="uia" >
                                <option value="" >SILA PILIH</option>
                                <option value="P" <?php if($row_rsSell['uia'] == 'P'){ echo "selected"; }?>>PILIHAN 1</option>
                                <option value="K" <?php if($row_rsSell['uia'] == 'K'){ echo "selected"; }?>>PILIHAN 2</option>
                                <option value="H" <?php if($row_rsSell['uia'] == 'H'){ echo "selected"; }?>>PILIHAN 3</option>
                                </select><br>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_rsSell = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSell));?>
</tbody>
```

i just amend my code..and still the other rows not run that java script..